# How to configurate EventTrackerStatusChangeListener in Spring Boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, axon

We're using Spring Boot + Axon Framework + Mongo (as eventsource, cqrs view)
Now I have to understand that **reply** of all my event is done. As I saw in documentation:

https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/monitoring-and-metrics#event-tracker-status
**EventTrackerStatusChangeListener can be configured through the TrackingEventProcessorConfiguration for a TrackingEventProcessor**

we can just configure EventTrackerStatusChangeListener and that it, I can react on all **reply** changes that I need. But after some research and trying, I realized that it can't be configured easily for auto configured trackingEventProcessors (auto named by packages path, or using @ProcessingGroup) is'nt it?

My question is: Can I configure EventTrackerStatusChangeListener to using it for all automatically configured trackingEventProcessors and how? If it's not, what the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EventTrackerStatusChangeListener` can only be registered for a `TrackingEventProcessor` (TEP) through the `TrackingEventProcessorConfiguration` class.
If you want to define a default listener, you will currently (Axon 4.4.2) have to define a default `TrackingEventProcessorConfiguration` to be used.

This can be achieved by using the `EventProcessingConfigurer#registerTrackingEventProcessorConfiguration` method.
Do note that this means that *all* your TEPs will use the same `TrackingEventProcessorConfiguration`. If you want to define a specific `TrackingEventProcessorConfiguration` per TEP, you will have to use the following function for each TEP you want to define:

```java
EventProcessingConfigurer#registerTrackingEventProcessor(
    String, 
    Function<Configuration, StreamableMessageSource<TrackedEventMessage<?>>>,
    Function<Configuration, TrackingEventProcessorConfiguration>
)
```

The first `String` parameter is the name of the processor (which you could have defined with the `@ProcessingGroup` annotation on your event handling components for example). The second parameter defines the message source to be used by the TEP in question. You can use the `Configuration` given to you in the `Function` parameter to return the `Configuration#eventStore` to retrieve the configured general event store. Thirdly, you would provide your TEP specific configuration.